# Nuxt i18n - How can I get current locale when generating routes?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I am having some problems while generating dynamic routes for Nuxtjs. I have a list of products that I retrieve from the API and I am generating single pages for them.

Everything works flawlessly for the default locale (I am using Nuxt `i18n`).

The problem is, that I want to call a different API if in another locale. I have tried many things to get the current locale into the `routes()` method but without any luck.

My code is:

```js
  generate: {
    target: "static",
    crawler: true,

    routes: function () {

      /* I WANT TO GET CURRENT LOCALE HERE FROM i18n
       so that I can call the correct API endpoint */

      let products = axios.get('https://example.com/v1/get-products').then((res) => {
        return res.data.map(product => {
          return {
            route: '/product/' + product.slug,
            name: 'product',
            payload: product
          }
        })
      })
      return Promise.all([products]).then(values => {
        return [...values[0]]
      })
      
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can't you import the i18n file into the `nuxt.config.js` JS one to get the current locale?

Comment: Please describe your failed attempts; will make is easier to spot the problem.

Comment: @dr_barto the problem is inside the `routes` function in the `generate` property inside Nuxt config. I am not able to access the current locale (neither via context, this, app, or anything else.)

Comment: Btw, what do you call `current locale` here? It's a build time, so nothing really dynamic here. Do you want to fetch an endpoint with all the locales or just one specific (how do you determine it)?

Comment: I've updated my answer [on Github](https://github.com/nuxt-community/i18n-module/issues/1423#issuecomment-1094407193) with a proper example. I thought you could import the locale at the build step somehow but I was wrong. Thinking about it twice, you indeed cannot have a static build + dynamic locale determined afterwards in the browser, at the same time. Especially because each user could have a very different locale. So, regarding my comment just above, the only available solution is to generate all the locales ahead of time and let the user determine which one he will be using.

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Answer (score 3):

As told [you here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/i18n-module/issues/1423#issuecomment-1087958480) by [Rafał Chłodnicki](https://github.com/rchl) who is the **maintainer** of the i18n module, this is not something possible (you can't know the *current locale* at build time).

And as explained in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71719960/nuxt-i18n-how-can-i-get-current-locale-when-generating-routes/71828035#comment126918503_71719960), the only way would still to generate all of the locales ahead of time, then let the end user arrive on the given page regarding the browser [language detection](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/browser-language-detection/).

Something like this in your `nuxt.config.js` should do the trick

```js
export default {
  generate: {
    target: 'static',
    crawler: true,

    routes: async () => {
      const availableLocales = ['fr', 'es', 'en']

      const results = await Promise.all(
        availableLocales.map(async (locale) => {
          const products = await axios.get(
            `https://example.com/v1/get-products/${locale}`
          )
          return products.data.map((product) => {
            return {
              route: `/product/${product.slug}`,
              name: 'product',
              payload: product,
            }
          })
        })
      )
      return results

      // return Promise.all([results]).then((values) => {
      //   return [...values[0]]
      // })
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it does not look like you nee the function localePath so the easy way will be to import the i18n config like this :

nuxt.config.js

```js
import i18n from 'i18n.config.js' //https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/basic-usage/

export default {
  i18n,
  generate: {
    target: "static",
    crawler: true,

    routes: function () {
       let products = i18n.locale.map((locale) => {
         axios.get(`https://example.com/v1/get-products?lang=${locale.code}`).then((res) => {
          return res.data.map(product => {
            return {
              route: '/product/' + product.slug,
              name: 'product',
              payload: product
            }
          })
        })
       })
       return Promise.all(products.flat()).then(values => {
        return [...values[0]]
      })
      
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to access i18n instance from the generate function, from my point of view it's impossible (I will make two more post about this so it does not poluate this response)

Comment: `i18n` is undefined here, since it's not in the scope.

Answer (score 0):

THIS RESPONSE DOES NOT WORK AND IS HERE ONLY TO SAVE YOU SOME TIME :)

1. I've tried to use an accessor set from the generate:before
   nuxt.config.ts

```js
import i18n from './i18n.conf'
import { generate, setGenerator } from './generate.config'

const nuxtConfig: NuxtConfig = {
  hooks: {
    generate: {
      before(this: any, options: any) {
        setGenerator(this, options)
      },
    },
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n', // https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/
  ],

  generate,
  i18n,
}

export default nuxtConfig
```

generate.config.ts

```js
import { Context } from '@nuxt/types'
import { NuxtOptionsGenerate } from '@nuxt/types/config/generate'

let generator: Context | null = null
let generatorConfig: any | null = null

const setGenerator = (hookGenerator: Context, hookGeneratorConfig: any) => {
  generator = hookGenerator
  generatorConfig = hookGeneratorConfig
} 

const generate: NuxtOptionsGenerate = {
  routes: async () => {
    // Here you have access to generator that contain a nuxt instance
    // But i18n is not accessible from it ;(
    generator.nuxt // it exists
    generatorConfig.i18n // i18n conf from nuxt.config.ts
  }
}
```

2. I've try to use a module as well, same issue

In the end I've juste coded the localePath function so I was able to use it in the generate and the sitemap.
(by the way it make no sens that i18n is not using the real route name and rather remove the _ from the name)

Comment: Why posting a non-working answer?

Comment: Sharing what I have try that didn't work so no ones need to try this again. 
I link to see what not to do in a thread, should I remove this ?

Comment: I'll be very glade to know what other approaches you tried because as soon as I have other idea I will try it because I'm really not satisfied with my "solution".
And I will probably end up doing the same this things you did and figure out that it's not working ':|
PS: thx for the info

Comment: I've tried to pass it somehow via a plugin, to maybe look for a custom Nuxt module, to try creating an universal cookie on the client and try to pass it somehow to the backend during the generation or simply to loopback it with the `serverMiddleware` of Nuxt. Using an external server was a no-go, even considering using a serverless function was pretty overkill. Looked for some Github issues and re-read my initial comment, then realized that indeed it was not logical to try to get the _current_ locale at build time.

Comment: Thanks for the insiste, I didn't try the `serverMiddleware` definitely tried the plugin version and than the module.